# AWS RDS Restore Snapshot Server not listening

Tags: amazon-rds, pgadmin, database-restore

I an a newbie to AWS, yesterday I created a RDS-Postgres instance and created my database. I terminated the instance and created a snapshot.

Today I restored snapshot(to a new instance), but the pgAdmin3 is unable to connect to the server. I keep getting "Server not listening" popup.

I checked the security group attached to this new instance and apparently it is listening to all inbound/outbound ports

I tried $nc-zv   
and I get
nc: connect to XXXrds.amazonaws.com port 5432 (tcp) failed: Resource temporarily unavailable

Am I missing something here?

thanks
Chahat

Comment: Are you using Aws console account? If yes then you just need to select snapshot and click restore snapshot button. Do not change any other setting.

Answer (score 0):

Ok So I was able to fix it, Apparently the port 5432 is not open by default. Needed to configure the security group